# Keeping mixpanel email subscriptions in sync

Tags: django, email, mixpanel

Can you keep mixpanel email subscriptions in sync with another system using webhooks and an API? Is there another way to do it?

I have a Django application that sometimes emails some users. I also use MailChimp to send newsletters occasionally. MailChimp offers webhooks and an API that I use in order to keep email subscription records in sync between my system and MailChimp's. Without that, I might end up emailing a few people who'd prefer it if I didn't.

I would like to use mixpanel to send emails to user groups targeted with their great segmentation tools. Unfortunately, I can't see a way to perform the same kind of syncing as is available with MailChimp.

Answer (score 1):

MixPanel do support webhooks, check this link to see it :
https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/webhooks